# Create nomenclature with 3 columns

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature, nomencl

I'd like to create a nomenclature which
has three columns (`Symbol`, `Beschreibung`, `SI-Einheit`).
So it should look like this:

[image]

My code

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

%%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[squaren,textstyle]{SIunits}
\usepackage{icomma}
    
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{trfsigns}
    
%%%----- Abkürzungsverzeichnis ------------------
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\let\abk\nomenclature                                       % Befehl umbenennen in abk  
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}              % Deutsche Überschrift
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}                       % Punkte zw. Abkürzung und Erklärung
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}                           % Zeilenabstände verkleinern
\makenomenclature
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%Aufruf für Abkürzungsverzeichnis im Text durch: \abk{Abkürzung}{Beschreibung}
    
    
%%%----- Symbolverzeichnis ----------------------   
%Um ein zusätzliches Symbolverzeichnis zu generieren wird mit Hilfe des Pakets nomencl noch ein zweiter Index erstellt. Dazu dienen die folgenden Befehle:
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\newcommand{\nomaltname}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\nomaltpreamble}{\markboth{\nomaltname}{\nomaltname}}
\newcommand{\nomaltpostamble}{}
\newcommand{\switchnomitem}{S}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\switchnomitem}}{\switchnomalt}{}}
\newcommand{\switchnomalt}{%
\end{thenomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\nomaltname}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\nomaltpreamble}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\nomaltpostamble}
\begin{thenomenclature}
}

%%%--------------------------------------------------------
%%%----- Beginn Dokument ----------------------------------
\begin{document}

    \printnomenclature

    \begin{equation}
    F_{\mathrm{L}} = i \cdot l \cdot B
    \end{equation}

    \abk[s]{$F_{\mathrm{L}}$}{Lorentzkraft [N]}
    \abk[s]{$B$}{Flussdichte [V s $\mathrm{m}^{-2}$]}
    \abk{ESB}{Ersatzschaltbild}
 
\end{document}
```

and my version so far:

[image]

The command to create entries `\abk[s]{xy}{zx}` should be still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted your solution to get the table format. Dome additional streamlining might be required, but at least it gives the desired result.

1. I use the `nomentbl` option of `nomencl`. This generates a `longtable` instead of a list.
2. This requires the package `siunitx` rather than `SIunits`.
3. I restructured the entries to conform to this format.
4. I added the `longtable` header to your macro `\switchnomalt`.

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

%%%----- Mathe ----------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{icomma}
    
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{trfsigns}
    
%%%----- Abkürzungsverzeichnis ------------------
\usepackage[intoc,nomentbl]{nomencl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\let\abk\nomenclature                                       % Befehl umbenennen in abk  
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}              % Deutsche Überschrift
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}                       % Punkte zw. Abkürzung und Erklärung
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}                           % Zeilenabstände verkleinern
\makenomenclature
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%Aufruf für Abkürzungsverzeichnis im Text durch: \abk{Abkürzung}{Beschreibung}
    
    
%%%----- Symbolverzeichnis ----------------------   
%Um ein zusätzliches Symbolverzeichnis zu generieren wird mit Hilfe des Pakets nomencl noch ein zweiter Index erstellt. Dazu dienen die folgenden Befehle:
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\newcommand{\nomaltname}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\nomaltpreamble}{\markboth{\nomaltname}{\nomaltname}}
\newcommand{\nomaltpostamble}{}
\newcommand{\switchnomitem}{S}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\switchnomitem}}{\switchnomalt}{}}
\newcommand{\switchnomalt}{%
\end{thenomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\nomaltname}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\nomaltpreamble}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\nomaltpostamble}
\begin{thenomenclature}
\hline & Symbol & Beschreibung & SI-Einheit \\ \hline
}

%%%--------------------------------------------------------
%%%----- Beginn Dokument ----------------------------------
\begin{document}

    \printnomenclature

    \begin{equation}
    F_{\mathrm{L}} = i \cdot l \cdot B
    \end{equation}

    \abk[s]{$F_{\mathrm{L}}$}{Lorentzkraft}{N}{}
    \abk[s]{$B$}{Flussdichte}{V s m^{-2}}{}
    \abk{ESB}{Ersatzschaltbild}{}{}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]